# Customizing the sort functionality of JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this very simple sort method:

```
sortByNumericAttr : function (a, b,attr){            
        a = a[attr];
        b = b[attr];
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
}
```

the idea here is that I have different objects with different attr that needs sorting (id,type etc.), so i thought instead of writing different sort function for each (where all the difference is only the sorted attribute), I'd write a generic method and pass the attribute to it.

So if it is written like this i can call it like:

```
arr.sort(utils.sortByNumericAttr,'typeId');
```

How can I achieve this or a similar effect, based on this function?

Comment: This code looks fine.....

Comment: yes, not working, javascript sort only accepts the function, the attr is undefined

Comment: Just as an aside 'is this possible' questions generally aren't a useful addition to SO's body of knowledge. Nor are any yes/no questions really. Most of them can even be answered by quickly consulting [the relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (where you can see the correct signature of methods, etc.). Getting help with implementing a feature correctly is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a function with another function:

```
function sort_by(attr) {
    return function(o1, o2) {
        var a = o1[attr];
        var b = o2[attr];

        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    };
}
```

And then call it like `.sort(sort_by('id'))`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list like this:

```
var list = [
    {id:5, color:"Green", name:"Audi"},
    {id:1, color:"Red", name:"Ferrari"},
    {id:3, color:"Silver", name:"Mercedes"}
];
```

You can create sort functions to sort this list for each of the used keys:

```
function sortById(a,b) { return (a.id-b.id); }
list.sort(sortById);

function sortByName(a,b) { return (a.name.localeCompare(b.name)); }
list.sort(sortByName);

function sortByColor(a,b) { return (a.color.localeCompare(b.color)); }
list.sort(sortByColor);
```

Comment: The idea, as i noted in my question, was to write one generic function and not a seperate function for each attribute

Comment: Ah, right, I see what you mean. And, of course +1 to Blender ;)